# calling gridview textbox textchanged event from a function from code behind as well as aspx code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text box inside gridview.I have already written some code inside its `textchanged event` as given.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AdjAMT" ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="grdAdjAMT" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%#Eval("ADJAMT") %>'  OnTextChanged="grdAdjAMT_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

What i want is to dynamicaly add a textchanged event for the same textbox from code behind also which is called from inside of a function .The code for both the textchanged events is the same.the code is as follows
Below text changed event is defined in axpx code as given above:

```
 protected void grdAdjAMT_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Given below is the function from which i want to call the dynamicaly added text `changed event`

```
protected void txtAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AdjustAmt();
    }
    private void AdjustAmt()
    {
       TextBox grddynAdjAMT = (TextBox)row.FindControl("grdAdjAMT");
     grddynAdjAMT.TextChanged += grddynAdjAMT_TextChanged;
     }
    void grddynAdjAMT_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //my code
     }
```

Can i use only one textchanged event?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use one event handler at a time, but u can `change event handler` at run time 
like this:

```
grddynAdjAMT.TextChanged -= grddynAdjAMT_TextChanged;//removing existing event handler
grddynAdjAMT.TextChanged += //add appropiate event handler
```